# Effect of operations on boost asio asnyn_read

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-asio

I have following piece of code to read data from a device:

```
    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t n) {
        std::cout << "handle_read: " << ec << " " << n << "\n";
        if (!ec) {
            std::istream stream(&buf);    
            while(!stream.eof()) {        
                char c[4096];
                stream.read(c, 4096);     //....(1)
                std::cout << "stream size: " << stream.gcount() << "\n";
                std::cout << std::hex << (0xFF & (unsigned char) c[0]) << " " <<     //....(2)
                     (0xFF & (unsigned char) c[1]) << " " << 
                     (0xFF & (unsigned char) c[2]) << " " << 
                     (0xFF & (unsigned char) c[3]) << "\n";
            }

            //Continue reading remaining data until EOF.
            boost::asio::async_read(*tcp_socket, buf,
                boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
```

Without `(1)` and `(2)`, num of bytes read in each cycle is around 1440.
As I keep adding the steps, `n` reduces to 512 and 200 respectively.

What is the effect of `istream.read()` and `std::cout` on number of bytes read by `async_read`? Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why I never get the `eof` error

Answer (score 0):

By

```
std::cout << std::hex
```

you have changed base for numeric.

So only at first handler call, you are printing the number of read bytes in decimal - `1440`. In second and next calls of handler you are printing value of  read bytes in `hex` base. You need to explicitly turn it back to decimal by `dec` manipulator.  So `512` as hex is `1298` in decimal. I think this value is close to 1440.